# Bad_alloc when declaring array, seems enough memory

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm coding to declare several large arrays and do manipulation with elements etc.

When the code gets to one section, declaring a temporary array, it throws up a bad_alloc after making about 1.8m columns.

Code is:

```
int** tempArray1= new int*[PHLengths[n-1]];

for(int i =0;i<PHLengths[n-1];i++) {

 tempArray1[i]=new int[PrimeDatL]; 

}
```

In the case being considered PrimeDatL ~417 and  PHLengths[n-1]~3630140.

Ordinarily I would assume this is just a matter of not having enough RAM (as it happens it will be underfilled as currently defined so I COULD declare a dynamic array and fill/expand along the way) however when I keep an eye on computer resources it goes to about 3gb/5gb then gives the error.

The one subtlety here is that I am using ubuntu on virtualbox, so could this cause memory address issues? Is it naive to think this error only occurs when I'm completely out of RAM?

I also tried declaring it earlier in the program to see if there were memory issues along the way, same problem.

Comment: Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits) if you are on Windows. You may need to switch to 64-bit compiler mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a 32-bit machine, you can only address about 4GB of memory, regardless of how much you actually have, so that'll probably be why it's flaking out between "3gb/5gb".

Comment: Ah yes that's a good point. I thought I had installed a 64bit VM but perhaps I did not...thanks!

Comment: Did you allocate enough memory to the VM? Seems like an obvious question, that would be something to look at.

Comment: Yeah, the problem I have now is working out how much is 'enough' memory (I can't allocate it all or the host runs out). I'll be writing another question regarding that (to do with mpz_class size)

Thanks!